# Android Action Bar Items Selected Effect

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In Android, to create a selected effect for Views, we can use a `StateListDrawable` or specify in XML like

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="XXXX" />.
```

Can we do the same for a `MenuItem` in the `ActionBar`? How?

Answer (score 1):

That's **`android:state_pressed`** for ActionBar, not `android:state_selected`.

Comment: I'll explain the question: There is something called as a selected state when defining a `StateListDrawable`. In XML it is specified using `android:state_selected="true"` . Therefore, when you call `setSelected(true)` for a `View`, it will use this `Drawable`. Is there anyway you can do this for a `MenuItem`?